# ":" operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, polymer

I'm using project polymer https://www.polymer-project.org/ and trying to precompile some Webcomponents in a Rails app.

I get an error in the file:

https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/components/firebase/firebase.js

So I guess it is malformed.

After I decompressed it with http://jsbeautifier.org/ I tried to use jstocoffee to check what could be a syntax error:

http://js2coffee.org/

And found this:

```
function Ua(a, b) {
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0
}
var Va;
a: {
  var Wa = aa.navigator;
  if (Wa) {
    var Xa = Wa.userAgent;
    if (Xa) {
        Va = Xa;
        break a
    }
  }
  Va = ""
}
```

What does the "a:" mean? Because js2coffee sends an error right there. It is a valid operator?

Comment: [**Ternary Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: `a:` is a **label**.  It's referenced from the `break` statement in the block of code following it. It basically sets up a "go-to" to the statement that follows that block of code.

Comment: @adeneo I guess OP is referring to the `a:` label rather than the ternary operator here.

Comment: The problem is that it marks it as an error here http://js2coffee.org/ it is well-formed?

Comment: Nested ternaries!  My favorite.

Comment: When you say that you got an error in the firebase.js file, what do you mean? Is it only js2coffee that errors out? Coffeescript doesn't support labels.

Comment: js2coffee 2.0 has been released very recently, I invite you to try it out again today.

Comment: @RicoSta.Cruz Thank you! Now indeed js2coffee 2.0 says that it doesn't support labels, version 1 just said 'error', so I tough it was bad javascript code

Comment: @Pointy You should post that as an answer, and I will mark my question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a:` in your code is a label. JavaScript labels work with `break` and `continue` statements as a (somewhat limited) form of "go to".

Thus this code:

```
a: {
  var Wa = aa.navigator;
  if (Wa) {
    var Xa = Wa.userAgent;
    if (Xa) {
        Va = Xa;
        break a
    }
  }
  Va = ""
}
```

works as if it had been written:

```
var var Wa = aa.navigator;
if (Wa && (Xa = Wa.userAgent) {
  Va = Xa;
}
else {
 Va = "";
}
```

So `Va` gets set to the empty string if the code can't find both the `navigator` and `navigator.userAgent` values.

Answer (score -1):

In the function

```
function Ua(a, b) { 
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0
}
```

Says: if a is greater than b then return 1; else if a is less than b return -1; else return 0.

the other a statement

```
a: {
```

is a global variable. It doesn’t have anything to do with the function.

Comment: `a:` is NOT a global variable.

Comment: The problem is that it marks it as an error here http://js2coffee.org/ it is well-formed?